# AWS Cross Account bucket access using external ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

We're working with one of our customers who made an external ID for write access to one of their buckets. While I can write to this bucket by assuming the role, my current is issue is that I need to give access to this *our buckets* to this external ID (our bucket is the source, theirs is the destination), but havent been able to simply give access to this External role. Am i missing something?

Comment: what do you meany by " give access to this our buckets"?

Comment: apologies for lack on clarity in my original question.

So i want to copy data a bucket from our account (Account A) to a bucket in another account (Account B). Owners of account B, gave us write permission to their bucket via an external ID, we can assume that role and write to their bucket. I however now need to give this role read access to our buckets (in Account A). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

> give this role read access to our buckets (in Account A). Is this possible?

Yes, generally it is. You have to add that role as a principal in a bucket policy of your bucket. Something similar to the following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "SomeNewId",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ReadOnlyAccessForARole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {"AWS": "<ROLE-ARN>"},
            "Action": "s3:Get*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can make it more or less restrictive, depending on your exact use-case.